# calculate union of matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have this df which I convert into a complete matrix. The 1's in df.wide represent missing data and the 0's represent no missing data in an experiment.

```
df <- data.frame(N_ID = c("1:36","1:66","1:36","1:66","1:87","1:30","1:36","1:88","1:66","1:36"), sample = c("sample1","sample1","sample2","sample2","sample2","sample42","sample42","sample92","sample95","sample30"), n = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

df.wide <- stats::xtabs(n ~ ., df)
```

Now I want to get a matrix that is sample x sample where the diagonal elements equal the sum of each column in df.wide aka the number of missing observations in each individual, and the off diagonal elements equal the sum of the union of missing data between each pair of samples. So in the resulting matrix that I want the cell for sample1, sample1 would be 2 and the cell for sample2, sample2 would be 3.  The cell for sample1,sample2 would equal 3, because total there are missing data at 3 unique N_ID for these two samples.  In other words, for each pair of samples, 0,0 should count as 0; 0,1 should count as 1; 1,0 should count as 1; and 1,1 should also count as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
`dimnames<-`(outer(
  1:ncol(df.wide),
  1:ncol(df.wide),
  Vectorize(function(p, q) sum(pmax(df.wide[, p],df.wide[,q])))
), rep(list(colnames(df.wide)), 2))
```

which gives

```
         sample1 sample2 sample30 sample42 sample92 sample95
sample1        2       3        2        3        3        2
sample2        3       3        3        4        4        3
sample30       2       3        1        2        2        2
sample42       3       4        2        2        3        3
sample92       3       4        2        3        1        2
sample95       2       3        2        3        2        1
```

Comment: No I don't think so.  As stated above, cell for sample1, sample2 should be 3 - because 3 N_ID's are missing in sample 1 or sample 2 or both.

Comment: The diagonal above is correct but the off-diagonal is not correct - because it is only counting up the number of times a sample pair has (1,1).  It needs to count the number of times the sample pair is (1,0), (0,1), (1,1).  Or, the number of times sample i and sample j are not both 0.

Comment: @rt11 Sorry, my bad. I misunderstood your goal. You can check with my update.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(N_ID = c("1:36","1:66","1:36","1:66","1:87","1:30","1:36","1:88","1:66","1:36"), sample = c("sample1","sample1","sample2","sample2","sample2","sample42","sample42","sample92","sample95","sample30"), n = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

dff <- df %>% 
  spread(key = sample, value = n, fill = 0)


matt <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(dff) - 1, nrow = ncol(dff) - 1) # initiate a matrix

for(i in 1:nrow(matt)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(matt)){
    matt[i, j] <- sum((dff[, -1][i] + dff[, -1][j]) > 0)
  }
}

diag(matt) <- sapply(dff[, -1], function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
colnames(matt) <- names(dff)[-1]
rownames(matt) <- names(dff)[-1]

matt
```

**Output:**

[image]